# Edit existing excel files using jxl api / Apache POI

Tags: java, excel

I am interested and would like to learn more about java , how to write into existing excel sheets / manipulating the existing data. I was wondering if you could give me an idea on how to edit an existing excel file and save it using the jxl api / Apache POI
or perhaps give me a sample program on how to edit some data in an existing excel file and then save it
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 33):

The tutorials [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) are very helpful and well-written. They use an external JAR developed by the Apache POI project.
Here's an simple example of editing one cell:

```
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("wb.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt([sheet index]);
    Row row = sheet.getRow([row index]);
    Cell cell = row.getCell([cell index]);
    String cellContents = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
    //Modify the cellContents here
    // Write the output to a file
    cell.setCellValue(cellContents); 
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("wb.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: At what point do you close the FileInputStream?  If you try to read from it after the output stream is closed, will it reflect all of the changes?  And, shouldn't the FileOutputStream be opened in append mode?

Comment: @eqbridges As I found out the InputStream is closed by default in the constructor. (I know you comment is over a year old but may be it will help others)

Answer (score 5):

One very important tip that I learned the hard way.
Open the OutputStream **only** after you have completed writing to your excel workbook. Zabbala's example is spot on and shows this correctly. If you open the OutputStream any earlier, your changes would not be written to the file after your program exits and you would be scratching your head as I did.

Answer (score 3):

I refresh the formulas with another tab for this I use the next sentence

```
HSSFSheet worksheetse = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
worksheetse.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

but it's necesary that you apply the method setForceFormulaRecalculation for all the tabs that have the formulas.

Sorry for my English

Comment: Note that `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);` may not work if the spreadsheet uses specific types of functions (with n arguments, which is not implemented in poi). However `worksheetse.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);` seems to work in this case.

Comment: @VassilenDontchev Can you please give some examples to show in which cases `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);` will fail

Answer (score 2):

Hello i have the same problem than neXGen. But strangely if i open the file with openoffice, it works!

Edit: perhaps i found a solution, put this after changing the values:

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
```