# Unable To Write Multiple Lines in Excel Using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a situation where I will be reading multiple lines and after some logic I need to write the lines in an Excel Sheet. I am using Apache POI for this purpose. However, the problem that I am facing is that, only the last line (from the loop) is being written to the Excel

Can someone please help me on this or provide some code snippet?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

```
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();   //or new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

    Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("Use \n with word wrap on to create a new line");

    //to enable newlines you need set a cell styles with wrap=true
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);

    //increase row height to accomodate two lines of text
    row.setHeightInPoints((2*sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));

    //adjust column width to fit the content
    sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)2);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-newlines.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

- [Using newlines in cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewLinesInCells)

Comment: Thanks Jigar. But What I am looking at is where I can write multiple lines to One Excel Sheet.

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-newlines.xlsx",true);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

Comment: I need to keep appending lines to an Excel Sheet. Like Open a sheet , write a line ... and again fetch another line from a loop and write that line in next row...

Comment: I haven't practically came across the thing you are at , but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521274/edit-existing-excel-files-using-jxl-api-apache-poi

Comment: The problem with increasing the row height like this is that your rows will skip numbers.