# Adding data to a new cell in excel without deleting the previous cell

Tags: java, excel, apache, cell, savechanges

When I try to add new data to this xls file, I lose my previous data. How can I add new information to new cells and save it?

My code is Apache POI:

```
Workbook w = new HSSFWorkbook();

Sheet s = w.createSheet("new");   

Cell a = s.createRow(0).createCell(0);    
Cell b = s.createRow(0).createCell(1);    
a.setCellValue(jTextField1.getText());    

try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("C://NEW.xls");
    w.write(f);
    w.close();`
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: Check our this question, it has good answers [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521274/edit-existing-excel-files-using-jxl-api-apache-poi)

Comment: use save() to save data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to input the sheet (using InputStream), add the record, and then save again. Right now you're creating a new Workbook Object and then writing it with the OutputStream which will just override what was already there.

Answer (score 2):

[ORIGINAL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521386/5359549)

The tutorials [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) are very helpful and well-written. They use an external JAR developed by the Apache POI project.
Here's an simple example of editing one cell:

```
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("wb.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt([sheet index]);
    Row row = sheet.getRow([row index]);
    Cell cell = row.getCell([cell index]);
    String cellContents = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
    //Modify the cellContents here
    // Write the output to a file
    cell.setCellValue(cellContents); 
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("wb.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Hope it helps